# how can i group them in two different groups use only single column

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql, sybase, powerbuilder

how can i group them in two different groups use only single column

sample data:

```
date_entry  time_start  time_finished idle_code    qty_good
8/8/2013    13:00       13:30            6            10     
8/8/2013    13:30       15:20            0            20
8/8/2013    15:20       15:30            6            5 
8/8/2013    15:30       16:25            0            10
8/8/2013    16:25       16:40            7            0
8/8/2013    16:40       17:25            0            40
8/8/2013    17:25       17:40            3            10
8/8/2013    17:40       24:00            1
8/8/2013    24:00       00:00            1
8/8/2013    00:00       00:30            1
```

---

result

```
                             idle_code   total mins.
        Idle time   #1  410:00  mins
        Idle time   #2  0:00    mins
        Idle time   #3  15:00   mins
        Idle time   #4  0:00    mins
        Idle time   #5  0:00    mins
        Idle time   #7  15:00   mins
        Idle time      #0,6     250:00  mins

(A) TOTAL IDLE TIME         440:00mins(idle time #0,6 do not include)
(B) TOTAL OPERATION TIME        250:00mins(idle time #0,6 only)
```

---

how can i get all the total sum of the idle_code 1 or how can i group them to get its sum??

sample sql

```
SELECT 
     dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry.wo_number,   
     dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry.qty_rejected,   
     dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry.operator,   
     dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry.reject_code,   
     dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry.qty_good,   
     dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry.idle_code,   
     dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry.time_finished,   
     dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry.time_start,   
     dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry.date_entry  

FROM dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry
```

Answer (score 0):

```
     SELECT SUM(dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry.time_finished,1,0)  
     FROM dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry 
     GROUP BY idle_code
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try

**CASE WHEN idle_code IN (0,6) THEN '0,6' ELSE CAST(idle_code AS varchar) END**

```sql
SELECT '#' +  CASE WHEN idle_code IN (0,6) THEN '0,6' ELSE CAST(idle_code AS varchar) END  AS  idle_code,
    SUM( DATEDIFF(ss, time_start, time_finished) )
FROM dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry
GROUP BY '#' +  CASE WHEN idle_code IN (0,6) THEN '0,6' ELSE CAST(idle_code AS varchar) END
```

Answer (score 0):

I’m not really sure I understand the full requirements but you can definitely try something like this. It’s similar to what Dante Ditan posted with the exception of calculating idle time.

```
SELECT idle_code, SUM(DATEDIFF(minute, time_start, time_finished))
FROM dbo.t_monitoring_pi_oper_entry  
GROUP BY idle_code
```

You can expand this by adding

```
WHERE idle_code in (0,6)
```